# C++ class type array

Tags: c++, inheritance

I am loading different types of derived classes from a file, which are of the form:

- 4-byte class ID header
- n-byte serialized data

Each of the classes are inherited from a same base class, but I have some trouble creating them elegantly. This is my current code (here Foo and Bar are inherited from the same type):

```
// read class ID
uint32_t id = ReadHeader(myFile);

// create correct class
switch (id)
{
    case ID_CLASS_FOO: myClass = new Foo(myFile); break;
    case ID_CLASS_BAR: myClass = new Bar(myFile); break;
    /* ... */
}
```

But I find this rather ugly, tedious and prone to error, since for every extra class I add, I need one extra define/enum member, and one additional line in the switch.

What I am looking for is something where I would declare a compile-time "type array" like such:

```
ClassTypes = {Foo, Bar, ...};
```

And then, when reading the file, just go:

```
myClass = new ClassTypes[id](myFile);
```

Is there some way to do this in C++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a factory class.

Factory definition:

```
typedef ClassType* (*ClassCreation(void))

class ClassFactory
{
    private:
        map<ClassId, ClassCreation> creators;

    public:
        ClassFactory()
        {
            creators[ID_CLASS_FOO] = &Foo::create;
            creators[ID_CLASS_BAR] = &Bar::create;
        }

        ClassType* getClassType(ClassId id)
        {
            return (creators[id])()
        }
};

class ClassType
{
    //etc
};

class Foo : public ClassType
{
    public:
        static ClassType* create()
        {
            return new Foo;
        }
};

class Bar : public ClassType
{
    public:
        static ClassType* create()
        {
            return new Bar;
        }
};
```

Factory use:

```
ClassFactory factory;

uint32_t id = ReadHeader(myFile);

ClassType* myClass = factory.getClassType(id);
```

Answer (score 0):

What about a static function in your base class that looks something like:

```
ClassTypes create(FileType myFile)
{
    // read class ID
    uint32_t id = ReadHeader(myFile);

    // create correct class
    switch (id)
    {
        case ID_CLASS_FOO: myClass = new Foo(myFile); break;
        case ID_CLASS_BAR: myClass = new Bar(myFile); break;
        /* ... */
    }

    return myClass;
}
```

At least that way, instead of

```
myClass = new ClassTypes[id](myFile);
```

you could do

```
myClass = ClassTypes::create(myFile);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your IDs go 0, 1, 2, 3, ..., What you could do is to create a `std::map` that maps each of the message ID to a function pointer to named constructor that creates the right kind of object for that ID.

```
class BaseClass {
   private:
   typedef (BaseClass*) (*NamedConstructor) (SomeType &);

   // The map.
   static std::map<int, NamedConstructor> id_to_constructor;

   public:

   // All the possible message types.
   enum MessageType {
      FooMsg = some_value,
      BarMsg = some_other_value,
      ... // potentially a whole lot more
   };

   // Add a named constructor to the map.
   static void add_handler (MessageType id, NamedConstructor cotr) {
      // Error handling such as duplicates left as an exercise to the user.
      id_to_constructor[id] = cotr;
   }

   // Function that applies the map.
   static void handle_message (int id, SomeType & my_file) {
      // Error handling such as a missing entry left as an exercise to the user.
      NamedConstructor cotr = id_to_constructor[id];
      cotr (my_file);
   }
   ...
};


class Foo : public BaseClass {
   public:
   static BaseClass* create_foo (SomeType & my_file) {
      return new Foo (my_file); // Or use a smart pointer.
   }

   // Member data and member functions elided.
   ...
};

class Bar : public BaseClass {
   public:
   static BaseClass* create_bar (SomeType & my_file) {
      return new Bar (my_file); // Or use a smart pointer.
   }

   // Member data and member functions elided.
    ...
};
```

You'll need some mechanism to register the named constructors `Foo::create_foo()`, `Bar::create_bar()`, etc. using the `BaseClass` method  `add_handler`. If you have 500 message types, that's 500 lines of code, but it will be straight line (no if, no switch) code.

The alternative is a switch statement with 500 cases. Yech.

So why a map rather than an vector? If you know the IDs will go 0, 1, 2, ..., a vector is fine. What if you have gaps? What if by design you have big huge gaps? For example, the message IDs might be Hamming-encoded so as to reduce errors.

Comment: Looks good. Doesn't appear too much different than the example that I posted. Has some extra features, like dynamically adding new child types.